# How to find the Exact Class/ID selector in Bootstrap CSS file to Override in Custom made CSS file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Sorry, I know this question looks silly. But I'm having trouble with finding the exact `ID selectors` to override those functions in my custom made `css` file

Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to find the exact `ID` which perform the relevant function (eg: changing background color, font color, hover background) in `bootstrap css` file so I can override those functions in my own custom made `css` file.

As an example, I have this code sample copied from `bootstrap.css` 
and think I need to change the  color of the `hover` when I mouse over the **drop down list**.

```
<!--This is the original code I copied-->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Softwares <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>
                        <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

So There is a dropdown list I have created (**Software 1, Software 2, Software 3**). I need to Change the color of Hover (When I put my mouse over any option available in Drop Down list).  According to the flow of the above code is it possible achieve that using these steps?

**nav navbar-nav -> dropdown -> dropdown-toggle -> dropdown-menu**

If I go in `dropdown-menu` in `bootstrap.css` I can see these code samples:

1)

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

2)

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
    border-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

3)

```
navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

4)

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

**And out of these 4 code samples I posted above, what is the EXACT location where I can change the hovering color of my Drop Down List?**

And please explain your answer in a simple way so I can understand it. I'm really exhausted looking into those code samples to find the exact location.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried overwriting all style with `:hover` in it?

Comment: No I didn't. Because I need to know the exact `:hover` without overriding all the `:hover`s in it.

Comment: Well, you can just delete it anytime, "trial-and-error" as they say.

Comment: And did you check the specificity used in those styles you included? You can use the specificity to check what exactly is being used for that specific class

Comment: Yes Sir I can understand that. But it is a time consuming task when if I had hundreds of lines of these codes. So learning to find the exact  or at least the close-enough location would save my time and day. :(

Comment: @Swellar: No I din't use specificity. Can you explain that?

Comment: This is an example of specificity: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover`

Comment: Why don't you just create a custom class in your css and apply it to your links ? If you properly load your custom css after bootstraps', those styles will override the bootstrap default ones.

Comment: @PierreBurton: To override  the bootstraps' I should find the exact ID. The problem is I can't. (I Can, but it takes considerable amount of time). To get rid of it, I asked for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Softwares <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>
      <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How come? I used what you provided

Comment: Be sure to put your own css after the bootstrap's css

Comment: **link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"**
Because of this `bootstrap-theme.css` even if I did change anything it won't take in to effect

Comment: Then don't include it

Comment: @Sweller: But I need to include it too. Because it has some amazing features like setting the shadow, blending etc...